# How to integrate payu native sdk with ios and android app

Tags: android, ios, iphone, payu

I am new with iOS and Android. Can any one help me out to integrate PayU native SDK with iOS and Android app? This app is not native, its using HTML/CSS stuff.

Or is there any reference site which is using it?

Thanks.

Comment: have you integrated in html for mobile apps? I'm looking for phonegap integration.

Answer (score 6):

Yes PayU has there own SDK for both android and iOS. You need to get in touch with payU guys to share the SDK and documentation for integration.

Here is the [github](https://github.com/orgs/payu-intrepos) link for payu sdk with examples. But you have to ask for the permission from payu guys.

[Reference app already using sdk](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.goibibo&hl=en)

Comment: ibibo app is using it. accept the answer once you are satisfied.

Comment: how i could check that ibibo is using it...?

Comment: Check the payu website, I think they have mentioned there

Comment: i m creating app using phone gap..not with native...how could i integrate it with payu..any idea..?

Comment: U need to get in touch with payu guys for it

Comment: he is asking for PayU while you are referring to PayuMoney! PayU is different from PayuMoney.

Answer (score 0):

PayUmoney has SDK for native android app. You must add these dependency in gradle file

```
    implementation 'com.payumoney.core:payumoney-sdk:7.4.4'
    implementation  'com.payumoney.sdkui:plug-n-play:1.4.4'
```

There are few step that you should follow to integrate payumoney payment gateway in android app.

You can Download example app, [android source code and PHP files in this link](https://www.blueappsoftware.com/payumoney-payment-gateway-integration/)

Please create merchant account on https://www.payumoney.com/merchant-dashboard/

Step 1 get merchant key and salt

Step 2 upload server side PHP files for checksum HASH

Step 3 add dependency

Step 4 get checksum hash

Step 5 start transactions